# $SL(2, \mathbb F_3)$ does not have a subgroup of order $12$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Using the characteristic polynomial I can prove that $SL(2, \mathbb F_3)$ does not has an element of order $12$, but how can I prove that $SL(2, \mathbb F_3)$ does not has a subgroup of order $12$?

Comment: Prove is the verb, proof the noun.

Comment: It also follows easily from the fact that $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: @Derek: If we know that $SL(2, 3) / Z(G) \cong A_4$, but that fact is not that easy to proof I guess....

Answer (score 3):

Since $G := \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$ has order 24, any subgroup of order $12$ would be normal (because of index 2), and hence $G$ would have an abelian quotient isomorphic to $C_2$. In particular we obtain an epimorphism $G^{ab} \to C_2$, where $G^{ab} := G/G'$.

To get a contradiction, you could proof that $G^{ab}$ does not contain an element of order 2 (indeed, $G^{ab} \cong C_3$).

Answer (score 3):

Outline for a proof:

With the characteristic polynomial, you can see that $A^3 = I$ in $G = \operatorname{SL}(2,3)$ if and only if $tr(A) = -1$. Count that there are $8$ elements of order $3$ in $G$.

A subgroup $H$ of order $12$ would have to contain every element of order $3$. Conclude $H \cong A_4$.

On the other hand $H$ must contain $-I$, so $H$ has a subgroup of order $6$. This is a contradiction since $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: why does containment of every element of order $3$ implies $H \cong A_4$?

Comment: @Stefan: then H would have 4 sylow 3-subgroups

Comment: and why is $A_4$ the only group of order $12$ with $4$ sylow $3$-subgroups?

Comment: @Stefan: then the action on $3$-sylows is faithful

Comment: is the action on sylow subgroups always faithful?

Comment: @Stefan: Not usually

Comment: guess I still have to do some homework cause I don't see it at once, but maybe I will get enlightened in a few days, if not I will ask again

Answer (score 1):

This is Theorem $2$ in George Mackiw's article :http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/George_Mackiw20823.pdf.

Comment: I looked at his proof, and everything except one piece is clear to me, he wrotes "$\alpha$ [the unique involution] commutes with every element of order $3$", why that?

Comment: The unique element of order $2$ is $-id$, see the lemma before.

Comment: ok. because of the special form of that element, now is clear!

Answer (score 1):

The sizes of conjugacy classes are $1,1,4,4,4,4,6$ (see [http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group:SL(2,3)](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group%3aSL%282,3%29)).

Now the two elements with conjugacy class of size $1$ are $I, 2I$. These have order $1,2$ respectively.

Any other element lies in a conjugacy class of size $4$ or $6$, so has centralizer group of order $6$ or $4$. In particular an element lies in its own centralizer so the order of any such element must divide $4$ or $6$ so cannot be $12$.

Comment: Just because it does not has an element of order $12$ does not imply it does not has a subgroup of order $12$, example $\mathbb Z_2^{6} \times \{ 0 \} \le \mathbb Z_2^7$, here we have a subgroup of order $12$, but clearly no element of order $12$.

Comment: Oh how stupid of me...I misread the question. Saw something about order $12$.

Comment: ok :) but nice arguments anyway.